# Why does videos.list not return private video metadata if authed as a Content Owner?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The Videos.list endpoint:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list`

Will return a `200` response code with an empty item block if you pass it an ID for a private video.  Here is the sample response for the videoid `n-RRGcbmMnA` which you can see here is private: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-RRGcbmMnA

```
    {
     "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
     "etag": "\"8jEFfXBrqiSrcF6Ee7MQuz8XuAM/Gv6WpqlPq0KQ3mrjyibWrI__dBE\"",
     "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 0,
      "resultsPerPage": 0
     },
     "items": []
    }
```

It actually returns that same response if you pick a random string of letters for the ID so it seems to give you that response whether the video is private or if it never existed.

If you are authed as the Channel Owner, you will get the detail for that video as a fully formed response.

However, if you use the `onBehalfOfContentOwner` flag and auth as a Content Owner account that has full control over that channel, you still get an empty return response.

This seems counter-intuitive, the whole point of being a Content Owner is that I can auth once and get all my data from that authorization.  Currently, to get any private video data, I have to manually auth to every single channel before I try and pull the video data.

Here is the Python script I'm using to grab our video data:

```py
import httplib2
import os
import sys
import isodate
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow
import pymssql

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = "WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0" 
YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

SQLSERVER = <our DB server storing the youtube database>
PORT = <port>
USER = <user>
PASSWORD = <password>
DATABASE = <db>
#grabs every videoid that has an 'update me' flag set to 1
IDQUERY = "SELECT [videoid] FROM [video] where [updateData] = 1"
UPDATESTATEMENT = """
    UPDATE [dbo].[video]
    SET
    [title] = %(title)s,
    [channelId] = %(channelId)s,
    [publishedAt] = %(publishedAt)s,
    [categoryId] = %(categoryId)d,
    [description] = %(description)s,
    [tags] = %(tags)s,
    [duration] = CONVERT(time, DATEADD(ms, %(duration)s * 1000, 0)),
    [updateData] = 0
    WHERE [videoid] = %(videoid)s
    """
UPDATEUPDATEFIELDONLY = """
    UPDATE [dbo].[video]
    SET
    [updateData] = 0
    WHERE [videoid] = %(videoid)s
    """

#YT o2auth flow
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE,scope=YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE)
storage = Storage("ytdata-oauth2.json")
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    flags = argparser.parse_args()
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)

#Establish YT connection
youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

#Establish SQL session and fetch ids for videos that need updating 
sqlconn = pymssql.connect(server=SQLSERVER, port=PORT, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, database=DATABASE)
querycursor = sqlconn.cursor()
updatecursor = sqlconn.cursor()
querycursor.execute(IDQUERY)
results = querycursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    videoid = row[0]
    response = youtube.videos().list(part="snippet,contentDetails", id=videoid, onBehalfOfContentOwner=<ourContentOwnerID>).execute()
    if response['items']:
        title = response['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
        channelId = response['items'][0]['snippet']['channelId']
        description = response['items'][0]['snippet']['description']
        if title != 'Deleted video':
            publishedAt = response['items'][0]['snippet']['publishedAt']
            categoryId = response['items'][0]['snippet']['categoryId']
            duration = isodate.parse_duration(response['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration'])
            try:
                tags = ",".join(response['items'][0]['snippet']['tags'])
            except KeyError as e:
                tags = ''
            updatecursor.execute(UPDATESTATEMENT,{'title':title,'channelId':channelId,'publishedAt':publishedAt,'categoryId':categoryId,'description':description,'tags':tags,'videoid':videoid,'duration':duration.total_seconds()})
        else:
            updatecursor.execute(UPDATESTATEMENT,{'title':title,'channelId':channelId,'publishedAt':'1753-01-01 00:00:00.000','categoryId':0,'description':description,'tags':'','videoid':videoid,'duration':0})
    else:
        updatecursor.execute(UPDATEUPDATEFIELDONLY,{'videoid':videoid})
    sqlconn.commit()
    #wait 5 seconds (api flood protection)
    time.sleep(1)

#make sure those values persist
sqlconn.close()
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get hold of a technical contact at YouTube that helped resolve this, posting the answer in case other people have a similar issue.  It is possible to have 'Analytics & Reports' access for a Content Owner without having 'Video Manager' access and you need Video Manager to see the metadata for private videos.

One chat to our security admin team resolved this issue!

Comment: Hey @Phil Davies, do you know the process for granting `Video Manager` access? I have super admin for our team but unable to find where to set this

Answer (score 0):

> Will return a 200 response with an empty item block if you pass it an ID for a private video.

If the video is private then the only way your going to see it is if the person who has access to it has authenticated your application anyone else or an api key would result in an empty list.

## onBehalfOfContentOwner

[Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

> onBehalfOfContentOwner string
>
> This parameter can only be used in a properly authorized request. **Note: This parameter is intended exclusively for YouTube content partners.**
>
> The onBehalfOfContentOwner parameter indicates that the request's authorization credentials identify a YouTube CMS user who is acting on behalf of the content owner specified in the parameter value. This parameter is intended for YouTube content partners that own and manage many different YouTube channels. It allows content owners to authenticate once and get access to all their video and channel data, without having to provide authentication credentials for each individual channel. The CMS account that the user authenticates with must be linked to the specified YouTube content owner.

Unless you are a YouTube content partner then `onBehalfOfContentOwner` wont work for you if you are then i suggest you contact your account manager they should be able to help you.

Comment: Apologies if it wasn't obvious but the 'and auth as a Content Owner account that has full control over that channel' bit is stating I am performing the request as a Content Owner account with full access to the channel.  I've tried the Account Manager path and they just divert us to the documentation, which brought me here based on this link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support